# From Where Do I Find Iron Python DLL's

Tags: python, ironpython

hi all from where will i find these dll's

```
IronPython.dll
IronPython.Modules.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll
```

is there any link to download these dll

regards

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? call ironpython functions from c#?

Comment: i have installed iron python in vs 2008 and coding using python windows application ...

Comment: from where do i get these files in vs 2008 as i have ironpython 2.7 but it will compatible with vs 2010 what should i do??

Comment: I am not sure about compatibility, try it.

Answer (score 1):

Look into: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython <version>\Lib` folder. Just reference all the DLLs in the ironpython folder. It should work.

For `Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737690/where-is-microsoft-scripting-core-dll) SO thread

Answer (score 0):

A Quick google for "IronPython" should get you to their page, you can also access their git repository [here](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/releases/tag/ipy-2.7.10) , there the easiest option to get the DLL files is download the zip version, inside you will see all the DLL files ready to copy and paste to wherever you need.

They also have a nugget package and some commands, you can check it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPython/2.7.10)